# Selected color in Yellow using webview

Tags: html, uiwebview, uicolor

I'm displaying some text in UIWebview.Now if i select some of text then the selected color is in blue. But i want to display the selected color in yellow.
And if i deselect then selected text will be in normal color.
Can any one help out???[image]

Comment: try : -webkit-tap-highlight-color: <color>; or ::-webkit-selection {}

Comment: I have done this one in this way

Comment: overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,0,1.0);
        padding-top: 5px;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light";
        color: rgb(1,1,1);

Comment: but when the webview load the whole background color is in yellow for few second

Comment: selected color is in blue

Comment: oh, sorry for that, can you try " ::-webkit-selection {background: rgba(255,255,0,1.0);} "

Comment: No, still not working